# Can you parse custom JSON data using GTL/AmpScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, gtl

I am trying to send out personalized emails using GTL and AmpScript but i was wondering if you can pass custom data in the form of a JSON object within a data extension
For example if a Data extension has the following fields:-

```
"id": 100
"name" : "qwerty"
"custom_data" : {"custom_text" : "abc", "another_key" : "another_value"}
```

Note that this "custom_data" field can have any other key : value pairs as well
So another record of data could have

```
"custom_data" : {"test" : "abcd", "some_key" : "another_value"}
```

Comment: Whats your use case?

Comment: Yes, but what you've provided isn't valid JSON.  Plus this topic is has been [**discussed a lot around here**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarketing-cloud%5D+%5Bgtl%5D+parse+json+)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't clarify my use case. My problem is more related to the "custom_data" key which has a text value passed as a JSON string. This field can hold any random json string. The problem here is that since the JSON string is dynamic and I wouldn't know what it is until it gets passed by a user, I will not be able to create a generalized template for all users. So if one record holds a JSON string of 3 attributes, another record may have 5 attributes that are all different

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your Sendable DE has a field named 'custom_data' which contains the following value for a Subscriber:

```js
{"test" : "abcd", "some_key" : "another_value"}
```

Then you could use the following code to display these values in your email:

```js
%%[
var @customData
set @customData = AttributeValue('custom_data')
]%%

{{.datasource order type=variable source=@customData}}
   {{.data}}
      {"target":"@customData"}
   {{/data}}

The value of 'test' is: {{test}}

The value of 'some_key' is: {{some_key}}

{{/datasource}}
```

This code will produce the output:

```
The value of 'test' is: abcd

The value of 'some_key' is: another_value
```

Note that GTL also supports arrays and nested objects too.